# WildFly 9: Allow HTTP only for localhost

Tags: http, https, localhost, wildfly

we migrating from JBoss 7 to WildFly 9.0.2 and have a problem when we use SSL/HTTPS. The HTTPS-Configuration works but we need a special configuration that HTTP is only for localhost is available.

In JBoss 7 we made this:

1.

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
change to
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="system-http"/>
```

2.

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
...
add server name
<alias name="servername"/>
```

3.

```
<interfaces>
...
add
<interface name="system">
    <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
</interface>
```

4.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
...
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
change to
<socket-binding name="system-http" port="8080"/>
```

In WildFly we made this:

1. and 2.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="http" socket-binding="system-http"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" />
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost,servername">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <single-sign-on path="/"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```

3. same

4.

```
<socket-binding name="system-http" interface="system" port="8080"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
```

but it doesn´t work (404).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [1] and try to express your need in other way, e.g.:

- try to use hostname "localhost" (or whatever is configured in your /etc/hosts)in inet-address
- try to use loppback attribute

[1] https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/9.0/interface/index.html